# How to implement keyword and location search with MongoDB?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, lucene, solr, full-text-search

I am trying to implement a web/smart phone app that allow users to search for places based on keywords and location and here is the requirement:

- Users shall be able to search by typing in keywords and location; Locations can be zip code, city/state or current location from the mobile app (lat and long)
- We would like to be able to customize relevance score; We need to be able to define our own relevance algorithm based on keyword matching, location matching and some other parameters.

We use ASP.NET MVC as our web development framework and MongoDB as a data store. We also maintain a list of all zipcode and city/state as well as their centroid (lat/long) in our database. Our thought is override the scoring that the full-text system provide (like Lucene scoring) with our own algorithm. I am trying to find the best solution to address this. I am wondering whether should we use MongoDB full-text search or try to use Lucene .NET or perhaps Solr? Any help/pointer/comment is always apprecated!

Comment: I would use Lucene.net for that instead of MongoDB

Answer (score 3):

So as a starting point, MongoDB does not have support for full-text search.

It has some regex capabilities and you can index on arrays. So you can do some things here, like building an array of keywords to make basic text search possible.

However, this is a long way from what Solr and Sphinx.

The other big problem you'll have is with relevance scoring. It's going to be very difficult to perform any type of server-side relevance scoring with MongoDB. There's no really efficient version of a server-side stored procedure. You'll likely have to pull the results to a client or server dedicated to that scoring.